# Unable to serve an mlflow model locally

Tags: deployment, localhost, mlflow

I have created an mlflow model with custom pyfunc. It shows the results when I send input to the loaded model in Jupyter notebook.
However if I am trying to serve it to a local port

```
!mlflow models serve -m Home/miniconda3/envs/mlruns/0/baa40963927a49258c845421e3175c06/artifacts/model -p 8001
```

I am getting this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/bin/mlflow", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/models/cli.py", line 56, in serve
    install_mlflow=install_mlflow).serve(model_uri=model_uri, port=port,
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/models/cli.py", line 163, in _get_flavor_backend
    append_to_uri_path(underlying_model_uri, "MLmodel"), output_path=tmp.path())
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/artifact_utils.py", line 76, in _download_artifact_from_uri
    artifact_path=artifact_path, dst_path=output_path)
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/local_artifact_repo.py", line 67, in download_artifacts
    return super(LocalArtifactRepository, self).download_artifacts(artifact_path, dst_path)
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/artifact_repo.py", line 140, in download_artifacts
    return download_file(artifact_path)
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/artifact_repo.py", line 105, in download_file
    self._download_file(remote_file_path=fullpath, local_path=local_file_path)
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/local_artifact_repo.py", line 95, in _download_file
    shutil.copyfile(remote_file_path, local_path)
  File "/home/subhojyoti/miniconda3/envs/python3-env/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Home/miniconda3/envs/mlruns/0/baa40963927a49258c845421e3175c06/artifacts/model/MLmodel'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error traceback, the model artifact can't be located. In your code, you are executing the 'mlflow' command from within a Jupyter Notebook. I would suggest trying the following:

1. Check if your models artifacts are on the path you are using Home/miniconda3/envs/mlruns/0/baa40963927a49258c845421e3175c06/artifacts/model
2. Try opening a terminal, then `cd /Home/miniconda3/envs` and  execute `mlflow models serve -m ./mlruns/0/baa40963927a49258c845421e3175c06/artifacts/model -p 8001`
3. MLFlow offers different solutions to serve a model, you can try to register your model and refer to it as "models:/{model_name}/{stage}" as mentioned in the Model Registry [docs](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/model-registry.html#serving-an-mlflow-model-from-model-registry)

Comment: Hi Julio, this worked : !mlflow models serve -m ./mlruns/0/baa40963927a49258c845421e3175c06/artifacts/model -p 8001                                            Should the port open automatically?

Comment: This command will start a service listening for HTTP requests on port 8081. If the port is not being used for another service. You can make requests using the tool you prefer like curl or Python package "requests". The MLFlow docs have  examples on how to consume a model, here is an example using [curl](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#deploy-mlflow-models)